# Regular expression for numeric range 0000 to 9999

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2008

I need a regular expression for a text field in my asp.net website

which should lie in between

0000  to 9999

it is not be

0 to 9999

Answer (score 24):

I think this could be:

```
^\d{4}$
```

Don't forget to escape it if you are using c#

```
string numReg = @"^\d{4}$";
```

Comment: The "^" ensures that the digits appear at the beginning of the text field, i.e. that there is nothing else before them.  The "$" ensures that the digits appear at the end of the text field, i.e. that there is nothing else after them.  "\d" is equivalent to [0-9], and "{4}" specifies the exact number of occurences of the "\d".

Answer (score 9):

Along with the other answers, you could also try this.

```
^[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: Using `0-9` is better since `\d` can contain more characters than one expects. The regex needs to be anchored though.

Answer (score 7):

Use a gigantic switch statement!

```
switch(val){
    case "0000":
      print "0000";
      break;
    // ...
    case "9999":
      print "I'm sick of typing";
      break;
 }
```

Comment: Very humorous. Though, I'm afraid of what will happen when you validate `9999` and get back `I'm sick of typing`. :-P

Comment: I community wiki'd this because I expected at least -3, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Using a little logic.  (Humorous, similar to "gigantic switch")

**Ruby**

```
def validate num
  return false unless num.length == 4
  return false unless num.to_i.between?(-1, 10000)
  num.each_char {|ch| return false unless '0123456789'.include? ch }
  true
end

puts validate '404' #false
puts validate '9321' # true
puts validate '-302' #false
puts validate 'AAAA' # false
```

Comment: Would 'AAAA' cause this to return true? I'm actually asking; I don't know Ruby.

Comment: 'some_string'.to_i returns 0 for stings that are not ints, so it would have before, but has been amended so it won't now.